# Appending elements to an array in a multidimensional array php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Within a `foreach` loop, I get the following values:

```
$name = 'foo';
$id = '1';
```

Now, the same name may appear multiple times with different ID's and I would like to form as array like this:

```
$data = array('foo' => array('1','2','3'), 
              'bar' => array('4','7','98'),
              'nee' => array('12','45','45'));
```

I have tried:

```
$data = array();

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
   $name = $row->name;
   $id = $row->id;

   $data[$name] = $id;
}
```

However, All this returns is:

The last value:

```
$data = array(   'foo' => '3', 
                  'bar' => '98',
                  'nee' => '45');
```

So not too sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append to the sub-array, not assign it directly. And if `$name` doesn't yet exist, you need to add it.

```
$data = array();
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
  $name = $row->name;
  $id = $row->id;
  if (isset($data[$name])) {
    $data[$name][] = $id;
  } else {
    $data[$name] = array($id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no value for your name , you need just to add it , else you append value to existing ones :

```
$data = array();

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
   $name = $row->name;
   $id = $row->id;

    if (isset( $data[$name]) && is_array( $data[$name]) ) {
       $data[$name][] = $id; 
    }
    else {$data[$name] = array($id);}


}
```

Comment: What if `$name` not exists in `$data` for first time ?

Comment: Okey i add else statement :)